# Determine closure and set of limit points for given set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$S=\left \{ \left ( x, \frac{1}{n} \right ) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x\in \mathbb{R}, n\in \mathbb{N}   \right \} \quad T= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : |x|  \lt y\}$$

and $$A=S \cap T$$

Find closure of $A$ and set of limit points for $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

We defined interior, closure and limit points today on class and this is for our homework. I am not very good at solving these type of tasks so if somebody can guide me how to find closure of some set in general(and prove that it is closure). My subject is called "mathematical analysis 3" so I don't know what tags should I put for this exercise. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have an idea, how $A$ looks like?

Comment: Try to think about what is $\overline{S\cap T}$ in terms of $\overline{S}$ and $\overline{T}$.